# Accessing web app http.get data securely

Tags: javascript, php, angularjs, http-get

We have a HTML5 app that uses a API accessible via http.get. I wish to keep the API URL address hidden from the public.

With this included in an app.js file, the javascript file is viewable.

```
$http.get('http://myAPIurl.com').success(function(data) {
```

The app is currently stored on a server that has PHP/MySQL capabilities.

Is there any way I can store my API URL in say a PHP file(which will hide contents) and then have something like an includes file within my app.js file.

https://jsfiddle.net/4y3cdpn8/

```
// Ionic Starter App

  // angular.module is a global place for creating, registering and retrieving Angular modules
  // 'starter' is the name of this angular module example (also set in a <body> attribute in index.html)
  // the 2nd parameter is an array of 'requires'
  angular.module('starter', ['ionic','ngCordova'])

  .run(function($ionicPlatform) {
    $ionicPlatform.ready(function() {



      if(window.cordova && window.cordova.plugins.Keyboard) {
        // Hide the accessory bar by default (remove this to show the accessory bar above the keyboard
        // for form inputs)
        cordova.plugins.Keyboard.hideKeyboardAccessoryBar(true);

        // Don't remove this line unless you know what you are doing. It stops the viewport
        // from snapping when text inputs are focused. Ionic handles this internally for
        // a much nicer keyboard experience.
        cordova.plugins.Keyboard.disableScroll(true);
      }
      if(window.StatusBar) {
        StatusBar.styleDefault();
      }
    });
  })

  .config(function($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider) {

    $stateProvider
      .state('tabs', {
        url: '/tab',
        cache: false,
        abstract: true,
        templateUrl: 'templates/tabs.html'
      })
      .state('tabs.home', {
        url: '/home',
        cache: false,
        views: {
          'home-tab' : {
           templateUrl: 'templates/home.html'
          }
        }
      })
      .state('tabs.list', {
        url: '/list',
        cache: false,
        views: {
          'list-tab' : {
           templateUrl: 'templates/list.html',
           controller: 'ListController'
          }
        }
      })

        // if none of the above states are matched, use this as the fallback
        $urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/tab/home');

  })

  .controller('ListController', ['$scope', '$http', '$state','$stateParams', '$window', '$location', function($scope, $http, $state, $stateParams, $window, $location) {

            $scope.query = '';         
            $scope.getOrders= function(query){

                   $http.get('http://myAPIurl.com').success(function(data) {
                    $scope.orders = data;

                   })
            }


                $state.go('tabs.home');
            }

  }]);
```

Comment: You could create an endpoint on your server which will work as a middleman.
`request -> server -> request to api`

Comment: anything downloaded to the user's browser is effectively public. So you can't hide a URL from them, unless you use a middleman URL as already suggested. What exactly are you worried about in terms of publicising this URL? Security? DDOS attacks? Something else?

Comment: Any hints to the code I could add to get a middleman URL setup? If I have 10,000 blocks of product data. They could just do a API request using something like Postman, get the JSON and setup a rival app/site etc

Comment: "They could just do a API request using something like Postman". Only if you don't implement adequate security, and/or don't put rate limits on your API for regular users (e.g. so a normal user can't just hammer the API and retrieve huge chunks of data and feed off it). Have a look at how Google do their APIs, their model is pretty decent. There are also lots of papers out there discussing good API design, and even companies who will do some of the standard work like security etc. for you (by going via their platforms)

Comment: Also, if you implement a middleman URL to obscure your original API URL, then in many ways you just transplant the same issues onto that, unless you severely limit what it's possible to do via that interface compared to the "real" API. But security by obscurity is no substitute for a robust design in the end.